# CSS: Positioning sibling elements in 2 columns and 3 rows

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position 4 sibling elements so that the first will take up half the width of the parent element, and the other 3 will take up the rest, positioned below each other.
The easy fix would be to wrap the last 3 in a parent element but this is sadly impossible since this is for a web application of which I cannot change the HTML

I've tried every positioning trick I know of but nothing seems to work.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
    <div class="child3"></div>
    <div class="child4"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the elements to be positioned like this:

|-------|-------|
|        |    2     |
|        |-------|
|   1   |   3    |
|        |-------|
|        |   4    |
|-------|-------|

See code for an example of how the positioning should look.

Answer (score 3):

You can try CSS grid:

```css
.parent {
  display:inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto;
  grid-template-rows:1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
.parent > div {
  outline:1px solid #000;
  padding:20px;
}
.child1 {
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:1/4;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child3">3</div>
    <div class="child4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css GRID, to layout elements in two dimension.

```css
    .parent {
      display: inline-grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .child1 {
      grid-column:1;
      grid-row:1/4;
    }
    
    .child1, .child2, .child3, .child4 {
      border: 1px solid red;
      padding: 20px;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="parent">
        <div class="child1">1</div>
        <div class="child2">2</div>
        <div class="child3">3</div>
        <div class="child4">4</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you simply updated to make your code the as me .. ?.

Comment: making your answer a simple copy of mine .. the purpose of SO is to provide different answers, not to update answers based on other to have similar ones

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent{
height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.parent > *{
    height: 33.33%;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
}
.child1{
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child3">3</div>
    <div class="child4">4</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is using `display: flex`. You can define the flow of elements to be set in columns, depending of the height of the parent element.
As you can see in the snipped the `.parent` has a defined height of the full height of the viewport (100vh). 
When a column is full (height of parent reached) a new column will be created.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0;
}
.parent
{
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}
.parent > div:first-of-type
{
  height: inherit;
  background-color: grey;
}

.parent > div
{
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">1</div>
    <div class="child2">2</div>
    <div class="child3">3</div>
    <div class="child4">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a css only solution for you,

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"> 1 </div>
  <div class="child2"> 2 </div>
  <div class="child3"> 3 </div>
  <div class="child4"> 4 </div>
</div>

<style>
 .parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
 }

 .child1 {
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 150px; 
  }

  .child2, .child3, .child4 {
      float: left;
      height: 100px;
      width: 150px;
  }
</style>
```